# Why does this "answer" contain a conversation transcript?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I came across [Integral notation for degree homomorphism on algebraic cycles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358073/integral-notation-for-degree-homomorphism-on-algebraic-cycles), and then I read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358073/integral-notation-for-degree-homomorphism-on-algebraic-cycles/1358186#1358186), which contains a screenshot of a long conversation between two users, the user who posted the answer, and the user who posted [the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358073/integral-notation-for-degree-homomorphism-on-algebraic-cycles/1358181#1358181).

I was about to flag the first answer as "Not an Answer", but it just seemed too bizarre to be a normal NAA, and it seemed to be accusatory.

Is there some particular reason for this that I am missing out on? Both answers have 3 upvotes and no downvote, by the way.

Comment: It boggles the mind that not only did it sit around for about 6 hours, but it was upvoted by three users.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's little sense determining *why* some user did this. They obviously felt that they *should* do that. They probably also had no reason to think that "Your Answer" meant something other than "Post Whatever You Want Here".  You see, when you get more than 1000 posts every day, and very few users interested in moderation, quality control becomes a bit of an issue.

A "not an answer" flag should have been sufficient.  If you wonder about the possible inflammatory nature of the screenshot, an "offensive" flag might have been a nice touch, though perhaps overkill. Maybe a custom "Please look at this crap, there might be something between these users" flag.

None of these options are required anymore.

Comment: Remarks at the end suggest it was at least posted in mutual agreement. I fully agree with the deletion, though.

Comment: @quid: Yeah, so that one could "drown in karma... or reputation or whatever". Highly enlightened conversation all around, if you ask me. Some of that probably could have been (and likely was) turned into an answer. But with the intention of offering "an insider glimpse into the world of discourse surrounding a math.stackexchange question," there was no point to keep it.